# Flutter CrossAxisAlignment with an if statement

Tags: flutter, dart

Sometimes want to align my `Expanded` class to `end` and sometimes maybe `start`. How do I align my `Expanded` class with an `if` statement?

```dart
 new Expanded(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(defaultUserName, style: Theme.of(ctx).textTheme.subhead),
                  new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0,right: 10.0),
                    child: new Text(txt),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like:

```
crossAxisAlignment: _alignEnd ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Comment: Because of my edit:crossAxisAlignment: _alignEnd ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,